# Error inserting rows into Oracle database via pyodbc (LONG value/LONG column)

Tags: python, oracle11g, pyodbc

I'm running into problems trying to insert multiple rows from a list of tuples into an Oracle table.

Here is the relevant SQL for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
column_1 NUMBER,
column_2 NUMBER
);
```

And here is the python code I'm using to insert records from a list of tuples into the table.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}', DBQ='somedatabase',
                      UID=username, PWD=password, autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

payload1 = (2.0, 4.0)
payload2 = (3.0, 6.0)
payload = [payload1, payload2]

# 1. this inserts (2.0, 4.0) into table
cursor.execute("insert into test_table (column_1, column_2) values (?, ?);", payload1)

# 2. this inserts (3.0, 6.0) into table
cursor.execute("insert into test_table (column_1, column_2) values (?, ?);", payload2)

# 3. error, only inserts (2.0, 4.0) into table
cursor.executemany("insert into test_table (column_1, column_2) values (?, ?);", payload)

# 4. error, only inserts (2.0, 4.0) into table
for item in payload:
    cursor.execute("insert into test_table (column_1, column_2) values (?, ?);", item)
```

The single record inserts work fine, but when I try either executemany or loop through each item and do a single execute I receive the following error:

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column\n (1461) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Has anyone else had this issue or have a solution?

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  I can only get it working without parameterized inserts.  As soon as I insert bound parameters, every insert after the first row fails.  If I try to commit the database between inserts, the Python kernel straight crashes.